# Allow only MM/YYYY date format in asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where user should be allowed to enter only MM/YYYY date format (Ex: 12/2013) in asp.net textbox. And i want to achieve this through client side coding (not through code behind). Have been struggling for long time, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Code? whathaveyoutried.com Give us something here.

Comment: This means validating the input. At what point would you like to validate? For example, do you want to make sure that the user is conforming to the desired pattern as they input (so 'a' is rejected) or do you want to validate after the textbox has "lost focus" (generating a prompt)?

Comment: Doesn't jQuery UI have a Date Picker that does this?

Comment: I want to validate while user is entering the input in the textbox.

Comment: Validate meaning alerting them to the error, or preventing them from making the error in the first place?

Comment: @PatBurke, preventing them from making the error in the first place.

Comment: Then you will want to use the the masking solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked out for me.

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeMonthYear" runat="server" 
     TargetControlID="txtMonthYear" Mask="99/9999" MaskType="None" 
     InputDirection="RightToLeft"></asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Answer (score 4):

If the user is manually typing this, then you would want to use a jQuery Masking Plugin like this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

This will enforce the format you wanted by simply saying: $(selector).mask("99/9999"); It will also add the slash in there for you automatically and only allow numeric characters.

If the you want a calendar widget, this solution can be combined nicely with the jQuery UI Datepicker which can also limit the user's input: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

use  [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and change dateformat:

```
$( "#textbox" ).datepicker({"dateFormat", "dd/yy"});
```